# displayDialogAsync() encodes provided url

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

i have this weird issue where i have a url with parameters that gets encoded as soon as i call displayDialogAsync() with it.

i can print the url on the page and it looks like this

```
https://{domain}/redirect?sessionUid={value}&userId={value}&url=https://{domain}/user/Home.jsp
```

but if i catch it in fiddler the request looks like this

```
https://{domain}/redirect?sessionUid={value}&amp;userId={value}&amp;url=https://{domain}/user/Home.jsp&_host_Info=Outlook$Win32$16.02$da-DK$telemetry$isDialog
```

notice how the & symbols in the url i provide is encoded to & while the parameters added by the displayDialogAsync method has an unencoded & symbol.

this makes the page i am trying to redirect to return a nullpointer.

i am sure this is something i am doing wrong or maybe some import that is interfering, but i can't figure out what.

has anyone else encountered this and does anyone know of a solution?

happens in both the latest outlook 2016 click to run version and office.com web client

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding which client (e.g. Olk 2016 C2R, MSI, Outlook on the Web, Mac, etc.) you are seeing this issue?

Comment: i get the problem in the outlook MSO 2016 desktop client version 1808 build 10730.20088 click to run

Comment: it also happens on Office.com web client

Comment: We are unable to reproduce this issue. Could you create a simple add-in(one that only includes office.js) that has a button call into displayDialog only and then check if you see the same issue? If so, could you then share that manifest for us to test

Comment: i found the issue, it was external.

the problem here was that i got the url in a webservice response, that webservice responds in xml, which i then parse to json (i have requested the WS to respond in json, but it has not been implemented yet). the xml2json parser i used did not decode xml encoded & symbols, and therefore returned them as &amp;.

this was made more confusing since the string was properly decoded when console.log(urlString) was called and therefore i did not notice that it was actually still encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happened because of improper xml encoding that was hidden in the console log since it parsed it when showing it to the user.